# How do I check if an input file contains letters or specific numbers?

Tags: c, file, validation

I´ve been trying to validate the input file. It has two conditions:

1. it cannot contain letters
2. numbers in the file must be in a range from `0` to `7` - integer only.

If both these conditions are verified, I want to print out `Valid` and if not then print `Invalid` on `stderr`. The program isn´t working correctly - I seem to never get `Valid` output.

```
    FILE *r;

    r = fopen("soubor.txt", "r");
    if (r == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened\n");
    } else {
        int c;
        bool alpha = false;
        bool outOfRange = false;
        while ((c = fgetc(r)) != EOF) {
            if (isalpha(c) != 0) {
                alpha = true;
                break;
            }
            if (c < 0 || c > 7) {
                outOfRange = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (alpha == false && outOfRange == false) {
            printf("Valid\n");
        }
        if (alpha == true || outOfRange == true) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid");
        }
        fclose(r);
    }
```

Comment: Would `01234` be a valid file or do those digits need to be separated (by one or more non-letters)?, e.g., `0,1.2  |3:4`? What about `00005 006`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem specification is not completely clear:

- when you write *numbers in the file must be in a range from 0 to 7 - integer only.* do you mean *digits* or numbers such as `10`? what about `01`?

From your precisions in the comments, the file should only contain white space and non-consecutive digits in the range `0`..`7`.

Here is a modified version with these semantics:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    FILE *r = fopen("soubor.txt", "r");
    if (r == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bool valid = true;
    bool last_is_digit = false;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(r)) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            last_is_digit = false;
        } else
        if (!last_is_digit && c >= '0' && c <= '7') {
            last_is_digit = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Valid\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid\n");
    }
    fclose(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me specify a little bit.. The txt file must only contain numbers from 0 to 7 - (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and cannot have any letters in it. This is an example of valid input file: 6 7
1 4 4 2 5 0 6
1 4 4 0 4 0 2
1 0 4 0 4 6 1
1 2 7 1 0 4 2
3 1 4 2 3 1 5
4 2 5 0 4 5 4

Comment: Is `10` a valid input file? `0` and `1` are valid digits but `10` is a number greater than `7`. How are numbers separated? Are `-` characters allowed?

Comment: Only valid unput is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.. No 10 or 00001 etc... All of the numbers are seperated with space making 2D array basically.

Comment: Then you should accept only white space and non consecutive digits between `0` and `7` and white space. I shall update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int isValid(const char *input)
{
    while (*input++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) *input)) return 0;
        if (isdigit((unsigned char) *input) && *input > '7') return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Use like (error handling omitted):

```
FILE *fp = . . . ;
char *buf = malloc(n);

fread(buf, n, 1, fp);

fprintf(stderr, "%s", isValid(buf) ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
```

Comment: `isalpha(*input)` has undefined behavior for negative character values on platforms when `char` is signed by default. You should cast `char` arguments this way: `isalpha((unsigned char)*input)`.

Comment: @chqrlie Does this apply only to `ctype.h` functions? Also what happens if `*input` is negative?

Comment: This indeed applies to all functions from `<ctype.h>`: they are defined for the same set of values as the return values of `getc()`, all values of type `unsigned char` plus the negative value `EOF`, which is usually defined as `(-1)`. These functions are usually defined as macros or inline functions using the argument to index into an array of flags determined from the current locale. Negative indexes below `EOF` will point outside the array, causing undefined behavior.